# How can I change the resolution of Avadon: The Black Fortress

Tags: resolution

Avadon is one of the latest Humble Indie Bundle games but I'm having real problems changing the resolution. It just pops up and there are no options to alter it or switch it to windowed mode from fullscreen.

Is there any way I can change the res?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

After first run a new file called `~/.local/share/Avadon/Avadon.ini` will be generated. You can edit this to change the game settings. Here's what the stock version looks like:

```
screenwidth=1024
screenheight=768
fullscreen=1
gamespeed=0
```

So just play around with `screenwidth`, `screenheight` and `fullscreen`.

In order for the game to pay attention to this, the option **Resolution and Window Size** must be set to **Ask at Startup** in the in-game settings.

Comment: How do I get into ".local" ? I see only "local".

Comment: @Drowz0r A dot in front of something makes it hidden so either show hidden files (Control+H) or just run `gedit ~/.local/share/Avadon/Avadon.ini` and it'll open it up. You'll need to have run Avadon in the past though or the directory and config won't exist.